# How do I compare now() and a unix timestamp for a delete query?

Tags: php

I have some queries I tried making to truncate records that are older than a certain number of days. They are in scheduled tasks and dont appear to be doing anything. I am assuming it is because it is trying to compare now() with  a unix timestamp (ex. 1553413592). How would I properly compare the dates and trunc accordingly? Thanks in advance for your help

```
$del_lot = new database();
$del_lot->where("DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , purchase_date ) > 2");
$del_lot->delete("lottery_ticket");
echo $del_lot->stmt;
```

For this particular one, all I want it to do is look at now(), and delete all records that are 2 days or older based on the timestamp in the purchase_date field. I have other similar queries that run fine, but the dev I had at the time did a normal datetime timestamp so the comparison works just fine for those.

Comment: In MySQL the return value of `NOW()` is converted to a number if used as such: `SELECT NOW() + 0;` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: @feeela but in this case `DATEDIFF` requires date/time arguments. So the problem is with `purchase_date`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to format your unix timestamp as a date / time.

Change,

```
$del_lot->where("DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , purchase_date ) > 2");
```

To,

```
$del_lot->where("DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , FROM_UNIXTIME(purchase_date) ) > 2");
```

As per the documentation:

> Returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. unix_timestamp is an internal timestamp value representing seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC, such as produced by the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function.